# Приложение не подключается к интернету

Tags: android

Указывал в манифесте permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1.MainActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

А вообще ошибка тут:

```
httpURLConnection.connect();
```

Приложение падает и в логах следующий текст:

```
03-27 14:51:54.461 25130-25130/zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1, PID: 25130
        Theme: themes:{}
        android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1.objects.ConnectorZabbix.goIntoZabbix(ConnectorZabbix.java:44)
        at zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.test1.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:105)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

В настройках устройства (раздел установленных приложений) не говорится, что приложение запрашивало разрешение доступа к интернету. Пытался установить apk-файл отдельно с устройства в надежде, что хоть так запросит разрешение, но нет.

Comment: Не подключается или таки падает? В логах есть что-то?..

Comment: Падает. Вообще весь метод под IOException. Я дополнил вопрос текстом ошибки.

Comment: У вас ошибка в том, что вы из основного потока пытаетесь в сеть сходить. Это нельзя делать. Надо сетевые запросы в отдельном потоке делать.

Comment: А как объяснить то, что в настройках устройства ничего не слышали о том, что приложение имеет разрешение выйти в интернет?

Comment: Не понял о чём вы. Наверное о том, что разрешение на интернет такое распространённое, что почти везде требуется и часто не отображается в списке разрешений приложения?\